# Default audio device gives an error on Windows 7 (x64) when trying to run VLC from CMD (VideoLAN, VLC)

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming, mp3

I use Windows 7 (x64) (Russian).

I want to stream live audio from my default audio capture device (microphone).

When I set up VLM settings using visual enviroment instruments -> VLM settings it all works fine.

But when I export the created settings/configuration to a *.vlm file and try to import it into VLM it gives me nothing.

I opened that .vlm and there is some text. So now I try to run VLC with default settings like this:

```
vlc -i dshow:// --dshow-adev= :sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=http,mux=raw,dst=127.0.0.1:8084}
```

but it dies giving me errors...=(

So what shall I do to do live MP3 streaming from my default audio input device using VLC  in non-UI mode?